# Preg_replace regex in PHP gives unexpected empty result

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using a regex to replace all email addresses in a string with a nice `<a>` to make them clickable. This works perfect, except for the case when there are *two words of a certain minimum length and a dash between them in front of the email address*. Only then I get an empty string as result.

```php
<?php

$search = '#(^|[ \n\r\t])(([a-z0-9\-_]+(\.?))+@([a-z0-9\-]+(\.?))+[a-z]{2,5})#si';
$replace = '\\1<a href="mailto:\\2">\\2</a>';

$string = "tttteeee-sssstttt mail@test.nl";
echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
// Output: "" (empty)

$string = "te-st mail@test.nl";
echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
// Output: "te-st <a href="mailto:mail@test.nl">mail@test.nl</a>" (as expected)

$string = "mail@test.nl tttteeee-sssstttt";
echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
// Output: "<a href="mailto:mail@test.nl">mail@test.nl</a> tttteeee-sssstttt" (as expected)

?>
```

I have tried everything, but I really can't find the problem. A solution would be removing the first dash in the regex (before the @ sign), but that way email addresses with a dash before the @ wouldn't be highlighted.

Comment: Before my brain is going to parse your regex: you _do_ know `{1,}` == `+` right?

Comment: Yup. I got this regex online, so it's not my own style. I'll fix it now, `+` is much clearer!

Comment: WTF? The string becomes `NULL` here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, minimum use case: `#([a-z-]+\.?)+@#`, which reaches the backtrack limit (use `preg_last_error()`), it cannot determine where to put things, as the `\.` is optional, determining whether to use the inside or the outside `+` is a lot of work. The default limit of `pcre.backtrack_limit` of 100000 does not work, setting it to 1000000 does.

To solve this, make it easier on the parser: the first `(([a-z0-9\-_]+(\.?))+` should become: `([a-z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-z0-9\-_]+)*)`, which is a lot easier to solve internally. And as a bonus, instead of the accepted answer, this still doesn't allow consecutive dots.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken. Good solution.

I was surprised to note that `(^|[ \r\n\t])(([A-Z0-9_\-]+\.?)+@([A-Z0-9_\-]+\.?)+\.[A-Z]{2,5})($|[ \r\n\t])` worked with eregi_replace which is deprecated.

So the working solution in it's entirety is: `#(^|\b)(([a-z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-z0-9\-_]+)*)@([a-z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-z0-9\-_]+)*)\.[A-Z]{2,5})($|\b)#i`. @Jonathon, I think you should accept Wrikken's answer instead, as I had no idea why it wasn't working before and I think this answer is more helpful.

Comment: Nice addition of `\b` too, and actually, I think we can forgo the `^` & `$` in that case, starting & ending it with just `\b` instead of `(^|\b)` & `($|\b)`. And `.museum` is 6 characters at the moment, as long as ICANN isn't yet handing our TLD's (they start next year with custom ones, I do not know whether they limit the lenght), having `\.[A-Z]{2,6}` should temporarily do the trick.

Comment: And just to be a bitch about it: how would you mail the good people at `http://пример.испытание/`?

Comment: Good point, and thanks for pointing that out. So we'd end up with `$search = '#\b((([a-z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-z0-9\-_]+)*)@([a-z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-z0-9\-_]+)*)\.[A-Z]{2,6}))\b#i';` But because of groups changing around $replace should also be change to: `$replace = '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>';`

Comment: Lol, I don't even want to go there. People will probably stick mostly to ascii for their email addresses and domain names for a few more years... I hope.

Comment: Hehe, in that regex we can of course drop the outer 2 pairs of `((..))`'s ;P

Comment: Indeed I assume they at least will have learned very quickly to remember their punycoded alternatives.

Comment: @Wrikken: One small nitpick in the second paragraph... Where it says, "the first 'blah1' should become: 'blah2'", the double open parens at the beginning of blah1 should be a single open paren. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for your search string instead:

`$search = '#(^|\b)([A-Z0-9_\-.]+@[A-Z0-9_\-.]+\.[A-Z]{2,5})($|\b)#i';`

Comment: Works great! Could you explain what was wrong with my search regex?

Comment: Hey, I just made a change to account for the fact that email addresses can contain dots.

Comment: You made the change that they can contain _consecutive_ dots.